# Liquibase error: "relation does not exist" when creating main table and table with foreign key in one change set

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to create two tables with relation one to many using liquibase and postgresql in java springboot application. There is only one entry in changelog.

When starting application I receive this error:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "public.main" does not exist [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE public.relation (id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, main_id BIGINT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_relation_id" PRIMARY KEY (id), CONSTRAINT "FK_relation_main" FOREIGN KEY (main_id) REFERENCES public.main(id), UNIQUE (id))]
```

Tables definition:

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "changeSet": {
        "id": "initial-structure-create",
        "author": "tcyborowski",
        "changes": [
          {
            "createTable": {
              "tableName": "main",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "autoIncrement": true,
                    "constraints": {
                      "primaryKey": true,
                      "primaryKeyName": "PK_main_id",
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": true
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "varchar(255)",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": false
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "createTable": {
              "tableName": "relation",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "autoIncrement": true,
                    "constraints": {
                      "primaryKey": true,
                      "primaryKeyName": "PK_relation_id",
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": true
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "main_id",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": false,
                      "referencedTableSchemaName": "public",
                      "referencedTableName": "main",
                      "referencedColumnNames": "id",
                      "foreignKeyName": "FK_relation_main"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

liquidbase version 4.3.3 - the same problem is with h2 in-memory database

If I split this json tables declaration into two json change files, run first table creation and after that second table creation tables are created without problem with correct relation.

If I try to run this this on clean database I get the same error as above:

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "include": {
        "file": "db/changelog/partials/initial-structure.json"
      },
      "include": {
        "file": "db/changelog/partials/initial-structure2.json"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What could be causing problem with running this in one go?

Comment: just guessing, but what if you remove `referencedTableSchemaName`? You are already in that schema.

Comment: It was error in json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake after changing logging to debug.

In both my json files above there is an error which caused only last action to be executed.

Corrected json files below:

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "include": {
        "file": "db/changelog/partials/initial-structure.json"
      }
    },
    {
      "include": {
        "file": "db/changelog/partials/initial-structure2.json"
      }    
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "databaseChangeLog": [
    {
      "changeSet": {
        "id": "initial-structure-create",
        "author": "tcyborowski",
        "changes": [
          {
            "createTable": {
              "tableName": "main",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "autoIncrement": true,
                    "constraints": {
                      "primaryKey": true,
                      "primaryKeyName": "PK_main_id",
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": true
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "varchar(255)",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": false
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "createTable": {
              "tableName": "relation",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "autoIncrement": true,
                    "constraints": {
                      "primaryKey": true,
                      "primaryKeyName": "PK_relation_id",
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": true
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "main_id",
                    "type": "bigint",
                    "constraints": {
                      "nullable": false,
                      "unique": false,
                      "referencedTableSchemaName": "public",
                      "referencedTableName": "main",
                      "referencedColumnNames": "id",
                      "foreignKeyName": "FK_relation_main"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }          
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `changeset` is executed in a transaction manner. Changes will committed at the end of the `changeset`

My suggestion is to create two tables in two different `changesets`.

> Liquibase attempts to execute each changeset in a transaction that is committed at the end, or rolled back if there is an error. Some databases will auto-commit statements which interferes with this transaction setup and could lead to an unexpected database state. Therefore, it is best practice to have just one change per changeset unless there is a group of non-auto-committing changes that you want to apply as a transaction such as inserting data.

Comment: If I split it into two changesets and try to run on clean database I still get the same error.

Comment: Found it, I made a mistake in json and only one action(last) was executed.

Comment: @TomaszCyborowski so your problem resolved when you split into two `changesets`?

Comment: @TomaszCyborowski ah okay I understood!